upload file from subdomain to subdomain
How To Upload file from https://subdomain.laravel.com/ to https://assets.laravel.com/
Example your project on https://subdomain.laravel.com/
'assets' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('assets/images'), // Path ke folder 'images' dalam folder 'assets'
    'url' => 'https://assets.laravel.com/', // URL publik untuk mengakses file
    'visibility' => 'public',


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

When you work with the files, you deal with the real(HD path) path, and here you can have under water rocks. explore first.

base_path() The base_path function returns the fully qualified path to your application's root directory.

just create a cname record pointed to later domain, and it should work with config you already didi

Generally, if you want to serve uploaded assets from another domain, you can use cloud storage.
Check out the AWS S3+CloudFront architecture.
The official Laravel Vapor also uses this architecture.
The idea of ​​"uploading to another domain" is wrong.

if you want to save your file to another subdomain its possible with two ways:
1: if your subdomain are in same server then you can locate with file directory path
2: If both server or different then you can make service for that to uploaf file by FTP or SFTP method its best way
Configure the FTP Disk in config/filesystems.php
'ftp' => [
    'driver'   => 'ftp',
    'host'     => env('FTP_HOST'),
    'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),

    // Optional FTP Settings...
    'port'     => env('FTP_PORT', 21),
    'root'     => env('FTP_ROOT', ''),
    'passive'  => true,
    'ssl'      => false,
    'timeout'  => 30,
],

Set Up Environment Variables
FTP_HOST=ftp.example.com
FTP_USERNAME=your_username
FTP_PASSWORD=your_password
FTP_PORT=21
FTP_ROOT=/path/to/root

strong textUpload File via FTP

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$filePath = storage_path('app/public/yourfile.txt'); 
$ftpPath = 'remote-directory/yourfile.txt';

// Upload the file
Storage::disk('ftp')->put($ftpPath, fopen($filePath, 'r+'));


Handling Errors
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

$filePath = storage_path('app/public/yourfile.txt');
$ftpPath = 'remote-directory/yourfile.txt';

try {
    if (Storage::disk('ftp')->put($ftpPath, fopen($filePath, 'r+'))) {
        Log::info('File uploaded successfully.');
    } else {
        Log::error('Failed to upload the file.');
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    Log::error('FTP upload failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

This code help to uploads a file from your Laravel application to a remote server using FTP.
